# Protobuf message over kafka mqtt-proxy

Tags: flutter, protocol-buffers, mqtt

I am sending protobuf messages to Kafka MQTT proxy, but I can't get the message value to be parsed by Kafka. I have registered the proto message to Schema registry and I can see the incoming messages but the values are garbled.

---

My current architecture is decribed by the following line

Mobile -> Kafka MQTT Proxy -> Kafka Broker -> Topic

---

And [this is the output I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WdYo.png). I don't know if I am missing a configuration but I cannot find any information regarding it.

---

Proto Message

```
syntax = "proto2";

message Location {
  optional double latitude = 1;
  optional double longitude = 2;
}
```

Maven pom.xml for registering proto message to schema registry

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-utils-parent</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.1</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>register-schema</artifactId>
<properties>
        <confluent.version>5.5.0</confluent.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>confluent</id>
        <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>confluent</id>
        <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-protobuf-serializer</artifactId>
        <version>${confluent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-protobuf-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${confluent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
        <version>${confluent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <schemaRegistryUrls>
                    <param>http://localhost:8081</param>
                </schemaRegistryUrls>
                <subjects>
                    <location-value>location.proto</location-value>
                </subjects>
                <schemaTypes>
                    <location-value>PROTOBUF</location-value>
                </schemaTypes>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>register</goal>
            </goals>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Flutter code snippet for publishing message

```
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_server_client.dart';

final builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
        final loc = locationPb.Location();
        loc.latitude = location.latitude;
        loc.longitude = location.longitude;
        final buf = new Uint8Buffer();
        buf.addAll(loc.writeToBuffer());
        builder.addBuffer(buf);
        this.client.publishMessage(
            "android/location", MqttQos.exactlyOnce, builder.payload);
```

Comment: "I have registered the proto message to Schema registry" -- How did you do this? Could you share some code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: added code snippets